# presentViewController not working after orientation change to portraitupsidedown

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5

Code is:

```
OptionsTableViewController *optionsTableVc = [[OptionsTableViewController alloc] initWithItems:itemNames andSelectedItem:-1 andOrigin:-1];

UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:optionsTableVc];
optionsTableVc.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

`OptionsTableViewController` is a custom viewcontroller which inherits from `UITableViewController`, a simple object

This code works well when on portrait, when rotating right once, or when rotating left once - but when I try to execute this code after the orientation changes to UpsideDown - it stops working - when I try to execute it, the current view gets "Flipped" (i.e from upside down to upside, or from landscape left to landscape right) and immediately disappears.

Comment: Do you have screenshots of what is happeing? Before and after respectively portrait and landscape would be helpful.

Comment: does the viewController you want to present allow the upsideDown orientation?

Comment: @user801477 IOS 5.1 doesn't allow you to set which orientations are allowed on a uiviewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

Your view controller that you are changing to probably is not returning yes to the following function for upsideDown

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{

}
```

if your destination view controller does not already have this function in it you'll want to add it and return yes for all the orientations you want to support (sounds like probably all). If you do want to support all orientations you can just return yes from this function and that should probably fix your problem.

Comment: Or you don't have the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method in your viewController class

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line fixed the odd behavior:

```
nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
```